# Same message on Azure service bus topic is received by multiple instances of the same service

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a service which is subscribed to an Azure service bus topic. My service is running on multiple pods in Kubernetes. Ideally, when there is a message on the topic, one instance should pick it and process it. But a few times multiple instances receive the same message. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

There are usually the following culprits:

1. Check that the processing time is not exceeding the maximum time set on the subscription via `LockDuration`. If that's the case, you'll have a lock on the message lost and other instances picking it up. That's normal behaviour for competing consumers pattern.
2. Validate your overall processing time is not exceeding 5 mins (currently the maximum time for Service Bus). If that's the case, your code should issue a request to extend the lock duration or configure the processor to do so if you're using `ServiceBusProcessor` provided by the SDK.
3. Ensure that all instances receive from the same subscription. If each instance has its own subscription, there will be multiple duplicates of the message.

Comment: I am not using anything with name `MaxLockDuration`, Is this keyword still valid in 2023? Each instance is using the same subscription. How to request to extend the lock, Can you provide some code? Do you mean to increase the value of `MaxAutoRenewDuration`, Currently it is set as 2 in my application?

Comment: LockDuration is the same. It’s an attribute of an entity you’re receiving from.

Comment: Sorry didn’t get you. Please clarify all the doubts in my above comment

Comment: LockDuration is the name. MaxLockDuration was a typo I fixed.